# Stuck transaction with enough fee rate

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, replace-by-fee

I've sent a Bitcoin transaction using the Bitcoin Core client and later realized the fee was too low (Fee 0.00005814 BTC ~ $1.69 USD)

https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/transactions/btc/ab8e9542604ca326a7b1f562feab9db621cc669fce2a6332303ce14714f9e79a

So I've added some balance to the same wallet and increased the fee for the transaction using the `bumpfee` command. (Fee 0.00030990 BTC ~ $9 USD)

https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/transactions/btc/4ec9b5b267fd4e58137d805544dbb6728f2f0a69df5913b6266405790092be58

But it's still unconfirmed after 18 hours. Am I doing something wrong here? Is this fee still too low?

Would it be interesting to remove low amount inputs from the transaction so it requires a lower fee?

Only one of the inputs has a relatively large amount of Bitcoins.

UPDATE: After waiting 6 days the transaction was finally confirmed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your replacement transaction pays 30 sat/vB, but the minimum fee rate to get into a block has been over 40 sat/vB for a whole day now (which is quite rare). I recommend checking [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/) to find out the current fees. You can bump the transaction again or wait longer, though exactly how much longer that will be is difficult to predict.

Comment: In my transaction there are 13 inputs, which increase the fee. Is it possible to change the transaction to use only inputs #1 and #12 ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you want a more detailed answer I recommend you post this as a new question.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118243/how-can-i-change-the-inputs-and-fee-of-an-unconfirmed-bitcoin-transaction @vojtěch-strnad

Comment: After waiting 6 days the transaction was finally confirmed.