# How to build a raw signed transaction with a FIXED fee?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, python

I was wondering how can we build a transaction with a fixed amount of fees already FIXED.

Let's have this configuration
2 Inputs (X:0 = 520 BTC, X:1 = 102 BTC) => 1 RECEIVER (+510 BTC)
Fees are: 0.001 BTC / byte

How can we build a transaction wheras we don't even know the signature size ? Can you show your steps please ?

Comment: Do you mean a “fixed feerate [sat/vB]” rather than a “fixed fee [sat]”?

Comment: I think the instructions I wrote here just earlier today would also work for you: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/118302/5406

Comment: Your answer uses RPC interactions. But, I'd like to know the steps to BUILD a new transaction in Python or something like that by specifying all conditions. This is more an algorithm conception.

Comment: Please edit your question to incorporate that information, drop the “bitcoin-core”-tag and instead add “python”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally found an algorithm which can fit to my wishes.

Available at : [Calculating fee based on fee rate for bitcoin transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103654/calculating-fee-based-on-fee-rate-for-bitcoin-transaction)

This can be easily converted into a Python code in order to build a transaction correctly.